# Difference between Ring/Cellular Network Topology?

Tags: networking, topology

When you deploy a network (enterprise scale), consisting of 1,000 computers and 18 routers, we decided to use a cellular topology (cell-topology). How many times can significantly reduce the amount of internal traffic by switching to the ring topology?

Comment: This is unclear and vague at best. Please explain what you mean with cell vs ring topologies, and what technology is involved. If possible, clarify what you mean by internal traffic (broadcasts? multicasts? something application specific?) and what the purpose of it's reduction is.

Comment: I meant mesh network by "Cell topology" and ring network by "ring topology".

Comment: Yes. Well. Switched, routed? Ethernet, something else? What kind of traffic? Nobody can answer this without a lot more details.

Comment: Routed, ethernet, local network traffic

Comment: There should be no reduction in traffic in a ring topology compared to a mesh topology. If anything, a routed full mech topology is theoretically optimal and can't be improved upon, from an efficiency standpoint.

Comment: And post last comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no reduction in traffic in a ring topology compared to a mesh topology. If anything, a routed full mech topology is theoretically optimal and can't be improved upon, from an efficiency standpoint.